# Getting error while installing tizen wearable packages from update manager

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

I have installed Tizen IDE on Mac OS Sierra. But when I'm trying to install additional packages such as emulator and wearable native app development, I'm getting an error as:

> [Emulator] Downloading/extracting failed!Cannot install the Tizen SDK
>   package.

Attached screenshot of error. Need Help!

[image: Installation failed ScreenShot Mac Sierra OS]

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Try setting it correctly in Package Manager settings.

Comment: Issue resolved after changing proxy settings.Existing proxy was blocking access to file download.

Comment: Then please make "changing proxy settings" an answer and accept it !!

Comment: @Armaan-Ul-Islam - Ok.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved after changing proxy settings.Existing proxy was blocking access to file download.